# mysql_num_rows returns 0, but the SQL returns normal values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-num-rows

```
$getPrd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN productscontent ON productscontent.productsID = products.id
WHERE productscontent.title LIKE '%".$search."%' OR productscontent.alltext LIKE '%".$search."%'
ORDER BY products.sortnr");

$num = mysql_num_rows($getPrd);
```

And the `$getPrd` returns values as needed, but the `$num` returns `0` - why is that?

Comment: According to the PHP documentation, `mysql_num_rows` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and `mysqli_num_rows` should be used instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but this is for an old project and it has 5.3

Comment: does your query return results? what do you mean by SQL returns normal values? you've to be more specific

Comment: mysqli should be used for both the query and the information function. Just because they only deprecated it in 5.5 does not mean that you do not use mysqli in earleir version. Indeed they had a notice to that effect in the manual since 2007.

Comment: @NishanthMatha yes, my query returns results. That's what I ment by normal values.

Comment: @DavidSoussan that's not really important right now, i have the same source elsewhere and it works so I really need advice that could actually help fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Can you verify that your connection isn't being closed right after the query is finished?  This might explain why you are getting results but no row count.  Can you explicitly give a connection parameter which you know will be valid before and after the query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not really sure how to do what you're suggesting, can you please be more specific with this part: "Can you explicitly give a connection parameter which you know will be valid before and after the query?" ?

Comment: This will render as an INNER JOIN

Comment: @Xeen, so how many rows do you actually get when you fetch them? Fetch them and count them please.

Comment: I was just thinking that the DB connection was getting closed before you could get a row count.  Also please try using `mysql_i` as David Soussan mentioned.  The code you are using has been deprecated and there may be bugs.

Comment: @DavidSoussan since it's a search mechanism, the number of rows is dynamic, but example would be I get `7` rows and the `mysql_num_rows` returns `0`

Comment: try passing `$database` as first parameter in query! $getPrd = `mysql_query($database,"SELECT * FROM products
LEFT...");` where $database is connection to your database like `$database = mysqli_connect("localhost", "your_user", "your_password", "world");`

Comment: What happens if you change `LIKE '%".$search."%'` to `LIKE '%$search%'`?

Comment: @MichaelDoye then the whole thing stops working :)